# Solve "Nullable value type may be null" on values1.Count in NetCore 6

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-10.0

Using NetCore 6 and `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` on project definition I have:

```
protected Boolean CrossBelow<T>(IList<Nullable<T>> values1, IList<Nullable<T>> values2) where T : struct, IComparable {

  if (values1[values1.Count - 2] == null || values1.Last() == null || values2[values1.Count - 2] == null || values2.Last() == null)
    return false;

  return values1[values1.Count - 2].Value.CompareTo(values2[values2.Count - 2].Value) > 0 && values1.Last().Value.CompareTo(values2.Last().Value) < 0;

}
```

But I am getting the Warning:

```
Nullable value type may be null
```

On a few places like:

```
values1[values1.Count - 2]
```

I am able to solve part of it using:

```
values1?[values1.Count - 2]
```

But I get the compilation error

```
`cannot convert from 'int?' to 'int'`
```

When trying the same on values1.Count:

```
values1?[values1?.Count - 2]
```

How to solve this?

Comment: The problem is that the nullable flow analysis apparently isn't being smart enough to spot that you've done the correct null checks on those `Nullable<T>` values. Note how the error is "Nullable **value type** may be null" -- `IList` is a reference type, so it can't be anything to do with that. You can shut it up using [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) `!`: `values1[values1.Count - 2].Value!.CompareTo(values2[values2.Count - 2].Value!)` and so on

Comment: Note that if you're using C# 8 or above, you can write `values1[^2]` instead of `values1[values1.Count - 2]`, and `values1[^1]` instead of `values1.Last()`, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are directly accessing the `Value` property of `Nullable<T>`. The compiler doesn't know if the values in your list at the last and second to last index might change between your null checks and when you're accessing these elements in the return statement.

The simplest solution here is to use the [null-conditional operator `?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). This would allow you to even remove the explicit null checks as now everything happens in one go:

```csharp
protected bool CrossBelow<T>(IList<T?> values1, IList<T?> values2) where T : struct, IComparable =>
       values1[^2]?.CompareTo(values2[^2]) > 0
    && values1[^1]?.CompareTo(values2[^1]) < 0;
```

I also simplified your array accesses using [indices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/ranges-indexes).

**So what's happening in above code?**

You're method takes two `ILists` `values1` and `values2` which contain values of `T?` (which is the same as `Nullable<T>` only shorter). Note that the `IList` instances themselves can not be null (or at least we don't expect them to be). Therefore we don't need any null-conditionals after the lists themselves. So the `?` after `values1` in `values1?[values1.Count - 2]` is not needed. The reasons you were getting warnings is because the element returned by the index operation may be null. Therefore we apply the `?` operator *after* we indexed the element we want.

Thanks to the `?.` operator execution now only continues to the `CompareTo()` statement if the value returned by the previous indexing operation is not null. As `CompareTo(object? obj)` takes a nullable value anyhow, we don't need a null check for the comparand. If the value returned by `values1[^2]` (accessing the second last element) *were* null then `CompareTo()` would not be evaluated and `null > 0` will always evaluate to false for `int?`. This is why we don't need the explicit null checks in the if statement.

The second line does exactly the same. Note that any comparison of `int` with `null` will return `false`. So `null < 0` is false.

Answer (score 4):

Things like:

```
values1[values1.Count - 2]
```

or

```
values1.Last();
```

are basically function calls and compiler cannot be sure they produce the same values on subsequent calls (say first time you call `Last()` it might return not null, but second time it returns `null`, compiler can't know it's not possible in your case). Just introduce variables, that won't hurt even without those warnings:

```
protected Boolean CrossBelow<T>(IList<Nullable<T>> values1, IList<Nullable<T>> values2) where T : struct, IComparable
{
    var v1Prev = values1[values1.Count - 2];
    var v1Last = values1.Last();
    var v2Prev = values2[values2.Count - 2];
    var v2Last = values2.Last();
    if (v1Prev == null || v1Last == null || v2Prev == null || v2Last == null)
        return false;

    return v1Prev.Value.CompareTo(v2Prev.Value) > 0 && v1Last.Value.CompareTo(v2Last.Value) < 0;
}
```

Comment: To save some vertical space: `var (v1Prev, v1Last) = (values1[^2], values1[^1])` etc